# PHP regex hashtag and special chars

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

ok, not sure if stupid or just monday.

It's actually quite simple. I have a textbox, in which I enter Text. A word gets marked with a hash (#), which then gets saved to the DB as the hashtag for that sentence.

Now, my funciton looks like this:

```
    public function getHashtag($text)
{
    print_r($text);
    preg_match_all('/(#\w+)/', $text, $hashTag);
    print_r($hashTag);
    die();
    if (isset($hashTag[0][0])) {
        $hashTag = $hashTag[0][0];
        return $hashTag;
    } else {
        return '';
    }

}
```

the print_r are just debug stuff.
All I want to achieve is to get the word with the hash. Works great, EXCEPT if someone enters a Word in french which has àèé or other characters in it. 
The output then just stops at the first special char.

```
#dfsdfaàèé asda sda sd asd aArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => #dfsdfa ) [1] => Array ( [0] => #dfsdfa ) )
```

any ideas? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use this expression `/(#[^\s[:punct:]]+)/`.

Reads as *"A `#` plus at least one character that is not white-space or punctuation."*

The `[:punct:]` is one of the [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Comment: Mr Tomalak, I thank you for your answer! :D This is exactly it. Need more coffee! Thanks man!